# Getting error while running nodejs code about syntaxerror

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting error when i run my node.js code in terminal.I am new to node.js and can't find any solution around internet.

My code:-

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
 console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

And error i getting when i run my code in terminal:-

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf600
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Comment: Its works fine for me. I'm using node 8.10.0

Comment: The code you posted does not reproduce any errors for me.

Comment: What program are you using to edit your Nodejs program?  It isn't a word processor, right?

Comment: i am using node 10.15.3

Comment: i am using textedit for editing in mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the current file text into plain text format,
go to **Format-> Make Plain Text then click on OK button**. and then save the file with .js extension.